# MVC C#: After login, the url go to ReturnUrl=%2FLogin

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I am trying to do form authentication on login in ASP.NET MVC.

After writing following code, I'm not redirected to the right page.

I think problem is in `web.config`, because before I have a page login generated with the new project.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".AUTHCOOKIE" loginUrl="~/Login/Index" defaultUrl="~/Login/Ok" />
</authentication>
```

Login Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Login l)
{
  if(Repositorio.AuthAdm(l.Usuario, l.Senha) == false)
  {
    return View(l);
  }

  return Redirect("Ok");
}

[Authorize]
public ActionResult Ok()
{
  return View();
}
```

Repository

```
public static bool AuthAdm(string Usuario, string Senha)
        {
        var retorno = false;
        using (var ctx = new Contexto())
        {
            var a = ctx.Administradores.Where(w => w.Usuario == Usuario && w.Senha == Senha).First();

            if (a != null)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(a.Usuario, false);
                retorno = true;
            }
            return retorno;
        }            
    }
```

Comment: your return url in your example looks to be the login page.....

Comment: you say this part?
<forms name=".AUTHCOOKIE" loginUrl="~/Login/Index" defaultUrl="~/Login/Ok" />

Comment: Can you include your login code? I assume it uses `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie`...

Comment: Model 

// GET: Login
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Login l)
        {
            if (Repositorio.AutenticarAdministrador(l.Usuario, l.Senha) == false)
            {
                return View(l);
            }

            return Redirect("Ok");
        }

Comment: Repository

 public static bool AuthUser(string Usuario, string Senha)
        {
            var retorno = false;
            using (var ctx = new Contexto())
            {
                var a = ctx.Administradores.Where(w => w.Usuario == Usuario && w.Senha == Senha).First();

                if (a == null)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(a.Usuario, false);
                return true;
            }

        }

Comment: public static Administrador GetAdminLogin()
        {
            string _Login = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
            if (_Login == "")
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                using (var ctx = new Contexto())
                {
                    Administrador a = ctx.Administradores.Where(w => w.Usuario == _Login).First();
                    return a;
                }

            }

Comment: @user3119254 please add this code you just posted as comments, to your question. It is impossible to read code from these comments.

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry!